# Batch file not in silence mode del /s /q /f file

Tags: batch-file

When i run this command in cmd or as a batch file it does not run in silence mode as /q should do, instead it displays "Deleted file - file"

```
del /s /q /f file
Delteded file - file
```

i hope this will help others as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact, quiet mode means it will not ask you for confirmation while deleting:

> /Q            Quiet mode, do not ask if ok to delete on global wildcard

```
>del /?
Deletes one or more files.

DEL [/P] [/F] [/S] [/Q] [/A[[:]attributes]] names
ERASE [/P] [/F] [/S] [/Q] [/A[[:]attributes]] names

  names         Specifies a list of one or more files or directories.
                Wildcards may be used to delete multiple files. If a
                directory is specified, all files within the directory
                will be deleted.

  /P            Prompts for confirmation before deleting each file.
  /F            Force deleting of read-only files.
  /S            Delete specified files from all subdirectories.
  /Q            Quiet mode, do not ask if ok to delete on global wildcard
  /A            Selects files to delete based on attributes
  attributes    R  Read-only files            S  System files
                H  Hidden files               A  Files ready for archiving
                I  Not content indexed Files  L  Reparse Points
```

In order to not show the output, you will have to redirect it to NUL.  From [Batch How To … Display & Redirect Output](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_redirection.php):

```
del /s /q /f file > NUL
```

Answer (score 3):

This may help you.

`del /q file >nul 2>nul`